# Get next site from an array of sites I created?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, awt

So the comment for the method below is basically what I need to accomplish.

I have a class called ResearchSite, which represents a research site I create(it's a simple red rectangle that can be created with a mouse press, and changed to blue on a mouse click. This method gives me a variable next, which is null. I'm confused on how to use this variable. The for loop is something I created, and I'm not sure if it will function.

How would I go about using the variable next?

Please note that the ArrayList named _research is something I created. It may not need to be used. The variable next will end up needing to be used.

```
private ResearchSite getNextSite() {
    ResearchSite next = null;
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // get next site from list of sites or from someone who has the
    //    list of sites.
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    for( int i = 0; i < _research.size( ); i++ )
    {
        _research.indexOf( 0 );
        i++;
    }

    return next; 
}
```

Comment: I'm honestly very confused about what you're trying to achieve. If you just want to get the next value of an array, a simple counter in the class will do fine. And why are you calling `i++` twice? What is the purpose of the for-loop? Maybe a [mcve] will prevent more stupid questions like these from being asked :P

Comment: Given what's presented in the question, it's impossible to answer as it's not clear where you want to get the next `ResearchSite` from. It's being assigned to `null` on line two. Think of `null` as meaning that `ResearchSite next` isn't assigned to any `ResearchSite` Until you assign it to an actual value, it will always be `null`. I'd expect `ResearchSite` to either be initialised using the `new` keyword, E.G. `new ResearchSite()`, passing in whatever constructor arguments necessary or to be populated by a method that returns a `ResearchSite`.

Comment: Incidentally, the `for` loop and `_research` `List` are redundant in this example.

Comment: As you can probably tell, I'm pretty new. Sorry for the redundant question. If I set next to a new Research site, how do I pull the next site from it?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need a loop to pull the next element from the array. You need a counter to point to the next element and increment that counter in each call. The variable must be outside the method (static or not - depends on your code)

```
public class ResearchSite {
 private static int nextIndex = 0;
 private ResearchSite getNextSite() {
  return _research[nextIndex++];
 }
}
```